# AssertionError : No value at JSON path "$.title" in Spring Boot Controller Unit Test with MockMVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, mocking

I'm unit testing a controller method to perform a get request. However, I'm facing difficulties with the jsonPath being unable to retrieve the specific field I am testing which is the "title" of my Content entity. The `getContent()` method itself is working fine, I'm unsure how to use `jsonPath`  to indicate the information I need.

Controller method I am testing :

```
 @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ContentDTO> getContent(@PathVariable
                                                 @Min(value = 1,
                                                      message = "{content.id.invalid}")
                                                      Integer id) throws ContentNotFoundException {
        Content content = contentService.getContent(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<ContentDTO>(contentMapper.entityToDTO(content), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Unit Test of the Controller method :

```
@WebMvcTest
public class ContentControllerTest {

    @MockBean //if a testcase is dependent on Spring container Bean then use this method
    private ContentService contentService;

    @MockBean
    private ContentMapper contentMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    private Content content;
    private Content content2;

    @BeforeEach
    void init(){
        content = new Content();
        content.setId(1);
        content.setTitle("test content title name");
        content.setDesc("test content description for a new content");
        content.setStatus(Status.PUBLISHED);
        content.setContentType(Type.ARTICLE);
        content.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        content.setUrl("http://test.com");

        content2 = new Content();
        content2.setId(2);
        content2.setTitle("test content title name2");
        content2.setDesc("test content description for a new content2");
        content2.setStatus(Status.PUBLISHED);
        content2.setContentType(Type.ARTICLE);
        content2.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        content2.setUrl("http://test2.com");
    }

    @Test
    void getContentValidTest() throws Exception { //TEST THAT IS FAILING
        //given

        //when
        Mockito.when(contentService.getContent(content.getId()))
                .thenReturn(content);

        ResultActions response = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/content/{id}", content.getId())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(content)));

        //then
        response.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title")
                        .value(content.getTitle()));

    }
```

Error I am receiving :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.title"
```

Additional MockHttpServletRequest message :

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/content/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"226"]
             Body = {"id":1,"title":"test content title name","desc":"test content description for a new content","status":"PUBLISHED","contentType":"ARTICLE","dateCreated":"2023-07-26T17:14:50.8809845","dateUpdated":null,"url":"http://test.com"}
    Session Attrs = {}


MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Example of a successful postman response :

```
{
    "title": "My Spring Data Blog Post",
    "desc": "A post about spring data",
    "status": "IDEA",
    "contentType": "ARTICLE",
    "dateCreated": "2023-06-17T22:39:52",
    "dateUpdated": null,
    "url": null
}
```

Comment: You defined `ContentMapper` as a MockBean, but there's nothing being mocked from that mapper, so `contentMapper.entityToDTO` does not return what you want.

Comment: I understand I stubbed the `entityToDTO()`method that uses ContentMapper and it worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the body of the MockHttpServletResponse, you will notice that it is empty. This means that the controller method returned an empty body as response. The response body is the result of `contentMapper.entityToDTO(content)`.

But in this case `contentMapper.entityToDTO(content)` returns `null` because `contentMapper` is mocked inside the test with `@MockBean` and no behavior is defined for it.

Since it seems that the `ContentMapper` belongs to the controller, I would also use the real implementation instead of a mock in the test. To do this, you would have to remove the field

```java
@MockBean
private ContentMapper contentMapper;
```

and add an `@Import` annotation to the test class:

```java
@WebMvcTest
@Import(ContentMapper.class)
public class ContentControllerTest {
```

I also noticed, that in

```java
mockMvc
    .perform(get("/api/content/{id}", content.getId())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(content)))
```

the last two lines are unnecessary for this test, because the GET request does not expect and should not have a request body.

Comment: I removed the request body and decided to stub the `ContentMapper` method instead of using the real implementation as I was getting errors with `@Import(ContentMapper.class)` Thank you for the help!